# Angularjs second dropdown depend on first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please i have a question. how could i create a second dropdown depend on select item from first dropdown.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select 
        ng-options="p.id for p in jobs"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>
    {{ selectedPerson }}
</fieldset>
```

Comment: i forget my tried code  http://jsfiddle.net/princearchimed/e72e43f4/

Comment: post your tried code

Comment: What is relationship between them? Question is too vague

Comment: There have only one select box. you cheater! :O

Comment: Here you go, i have updated my answer. Check the JSFIDDLE i have attached in the answer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a interesting example to show you how the select list can depend on another. In fact, the select options of a list can be made dependent on the value of the first select list.

HTML

Controller

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.jobs1 = [
    {
        "id": 600,
        "sector": "Controlling",
        "cost": 4700
    },
    {
        "id": 600,
        "sector": "finance",
        "cost": 4700

    },
    {
        "id": 40,
        "sector": "IT",
        "cost": 7600

    },
    {
        "id": 50,
        "sector": "Controlling",
        "cost": 4600

    },
    {
        "id": 50,
        "sector": "IT",
        "cost": 4600

    },{
        "id": 41,
        "sector": "Controlling",
        "cost": 1100

    },
    {
        "id": 41,
        "sector": "IT",
        "cost": 1100

    }
];
$scope.jobs2 = [];

$scope.firstSelectChange = function(){
  $scope.jobs2 = [];
  $scope.selectedPerson2 = '';
 for(var i=0; i<$scope.jobs1.length; i++){
       if($scope.jobs1[i].id === $scope.selectedPerson1.id){
           $scope.jobs2.push($scope.jobs1[i]);
       }
    }
}

});
```

You can observe that when you select a option in first select list then the options on second select list are changed dynamically.

For more experiment and observation here is the link to working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ptxbbyj8/)

Comment: like you can see when i select one item on first dropdown, the second show me alway all sector. The idea is when i select id=600, on a second would just appear a two sector :'Controlling and finance' 
  http://jsfiddle.net/princearchimed/ue3eabdd/

Comment: Here you go, i have updated my answer. Check the JSFIDDLE i have attached in the answer above.

Comment: You welcome. I would appreciate a up vote and tick mark on the answer. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only select one select option at a time. other wise you can use `multiple` in your select box

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select multiple
            ng-options="p.id for p in jobs"
            ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-change="addItems()"></select> 


        <select  
            ng-options="p.id for p in selectedPerson"
            ng-model="selecteditems" ng-change="addItems()"></select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e72e43f4/2/)

Comment: Why here we need select box? we can show the selected value in label field? correct? I think OP want to something!  I thought He's on  now yoga mode! he will be come back :(

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran yeah it makes no sense to me too. at least he can use a checkbox or something :D :D

Comment: @ sachila ranawaka and Ramesh Rajendranm, my really goal was when i select one item on first dropdown, the second show me alway all sector. The idea is when i select id=600, on a second would just appear a two sector :'Controlling and finance' or have a possibilty to select all 'id' and a second dropdown would show me all 'sector' for a selected 'id': thanks